# Optimizing query with left outer join and comma-separated-string

Tags: t-sql

I have tables in my db called Items, which are in a relationships with ItemParents table. One item can have one parent, one parent can have multiple items (something like file-folder tree structure). I have a third table called ParentPermissions and in this table I have the permissions if a user depending on its role can view the parent. If he can view the parent, he can view the item too. In this table we save the relationships between the parent and the userroles that CAN NOT view the parent.

For example, for parentId = 1, if there is no data in the table ParentPermissions for this parent, all users can see it. If there is data with values "5,6" in ParentPermissions for parentId = 1, then the users with roles 5 and6 can't see this folder. Users with role 4 can see it.

This is my query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Items item
INNER JOIN ItemParents parent ON parent.id = item.parentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ParentPermissions permissions ON permissions.folderId = parent.id
WHERE permissions.view IS NULL OR (permissions.view != CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @userRole + ',%') AND permissions.view != CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @userRole) AND permissions.view != CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), '%,' +  @userRole))
```

I want to somehow optimize this query because it is called a lot of times. How do I do that?

Comment: Can make structural changes? Create view, trigger or other SQL table - are you allowed? Do you need to optimize this particular query only?

Comment: I can create temporary tables, but not permanent changes.

Comment: It will be better if we can change the way permission are recorded. Instead of using `CSV` to use `ParentID - GroupID`. If you are not allowed or is not easy to make such change, you can create `trigger` on the `ParentPermissions ` table  who is populating/managing a `ParentPermissionsPrecalculated` table. Then you are going to use the later when securiy is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Create temporary table containing only the DENY documents for the current user

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #CurrentUserParentPermissions 
   (
       ParentID INT
   )

   INSERT INTO #CurrentUserParentPermissions (ParentID)
   SELECT *
   FROM ParentPermissions 
   WHERE (permissions.view != CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @userRole + ',%') ....
   ```
2. Then apply the left join using this table

   ```
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM Items item
   INNER JOIN ItemParents parent ON parent.id = item.parentId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN #CurrentUserParentPermissions permissions ON permissions.folderId = parent.id
   WHERE permissions.view IS NULL;
   ```